# Are there any multi-tenant role based authentication solutions out there?

Tags: authentication

I'm writing a cloud based multi tenant application.  I'd like tenants to manage their own users - add, remove users - manage permissions etc.  I'm kind of hoping there is a provider out there that already handles this.  I don't want to have to write all those screens.  I'd rather set up the list of roles and permissions and let the tenant admins go in and manage their users.

All I want if for a logged in user to get a list of permissions.  I can code against those permissions in my application.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure**: Answer provided by an Auth0 employee.

---

If I understood correctly you should be able to accomplish your goals using Auth0 solutions aimed at multi-tenant applications. There are a couple of resources that should help you get started, although I would give particular focus to [Using Auth0 with Multi-tenant Apps](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/using-auth0-with-multi-tenant-apps).

In the section ([A single Auth0 account for all tenants](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/using-auth0-with-multi-tenant-apps#a-single-auth0-account-for-all-tenants)) you'll notice that the simpler management option would be to only have a single Auth0 account, however, your use case could be accomplished by having each tenant have their own separate account which would make it possible for them to manage their users from Auth0 built-in dashboard. (**no need for you to write custom screens**)

> One account for all tenants is simpler and allows you to manage them in one place.
>
> Only **if you want to share access to the dashboard with tenants would a separate Auth0 account per tenant be required**.

Also check section ([Different roles for each tenant](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/using-auth0-with-multi-tenant-apps#different-roles-for-each-tenant)) for a possible way on how to handle your user role and permission information.

Additionally, there's a sample multi-tenant app where each tenant has its own Auth0 account on [Github](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-multitenant-spa-api-sample) if you want to delve into the more technical aspects.

On the other hand, if your tenants already have their own authentication solution in place you can easily integrate that with your Auth0 enabled SaaS application. See [Building multi-tenant, SaaS applications with Azure AD and Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/building-multi-tenant-saas-applications-with-azure-active-directory) for a detailed example on Azure AD integration, but don't think you would be restricted only to Azure AD integration as Auth0 supports a wide range of identity providers ([Identity Providers Supported by Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/identityproviders#enterprise)).